# HTTP Auth via PHP - PHP_AUTH_USER not set?

Tags: php, http, authentication, server-variables

I tried to implement a small authentication via http and copied this bit of code from the net to check whether this will work properly:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
        echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
    }
?>
```

However, my browser always ask for a username and password but never outputs anything until i cancel. Therefore i think that `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` is never set! What might be the problem? I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Server with `Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.0.63 OpenSSL/0.9.7d DAV/2 Server`.

Comment: @Jonny Keogh: Safari 5 and Firefox 5, however andreas already solved the problem by checking for CGI/FCGI.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Run phpinfo(). if "Server API" is CGI/FCGI, you can pretty much forget it as there is no sensible way to use HTTP auth from PHP.

Comment: Actually, it will work with FastCGI. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56715271/1772821

Answer (score 23):

For PHP-CGI:

in .htaccess add this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

and at the beginning of your script add this:

```
list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':' , base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));
```

Comment: Praise the lord for your answer. I was sharpening my wrist slitting knife when this finally solved my problems.

Comment: looks like you don't need this line: `list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':' , base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));`

Comment: @Shawn list($... is for the requesting client.

Comment: The .htaccess fix is what worked for me. Notice I had to put it at the end of it, else my codeigniter installation wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

Enable PHP-FPM and it will start working.

```
$valid_passwords = array ("test" => "test");
$valid_users = array_keys($valid_passwords);

$user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$pass = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

$validated = (in_array($user, $valid_users)) && ($pass == $valid_passwords[$user]);

if (!$validated) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Test"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    die ("Not authorized");
}
```