# http basic auth - PHP_AUTH_USER & PHP_AUTH_PW not being set

Tags: php, apache, basic-authentication

I've looked at several other questions on stackoverflow dealing with this issue [HTTP Auth via PHP - PHP_AUTH_USER not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053306/http-auth-via-php-php-auth-user-not-set) and [PHP_AUTH_USER not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663520/php-auth-user-not-set) , but they all point at issues with "Server API" being set to CGI, for me it's set to "Apache 2.0 Handler".

I'm using UBUNTU 12.04LTS.

I have a simple script in my docroot called my.php:

```
<?php
echo "Username: " . $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] . ", Password: " . $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"];
?
```

When I run wget, I can see that both are empty:

```
wget -v --http-user=johnsmith --http-password=mypassword http://192.168.1.163/my.php
```

returns:

```
Username: , Password:
```

I have the following apache modules enabled:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled
alias.conf       authn_file.load       authz_host.load  autoindex.load  deflate.load  env.load   negotiation.conf  php5.load        rewrite.load   status.conf
alias.load       authz_default.load    authz_user.load  cgi.load        dir.conf      mime.conf  negotiation.load  reqtimeout.conf  setenvif.conf  status.load
auth_basic.load  authz_groupfile.load  autoindex.conf   deflate.conf    dir.load      mime.load  php5.conf         reqtimeout.load  setenvif.load
```

I also tried adding a line to my .htaccess for "AuthType Basic" to no avail.

Is there something else that needs to be set or config'ed?

Comment: is that page actually PW protected? as far as I remember, wget won't send the credentials unless it gets a 401 response code.

Comment: Seconding @MarcB -- I believe .htaccess is considered to be "external" authentication and will not show up as php_auth_user. Modify your script to send the proper 401 request -- without it, the credentials won't be sent (otherwise, you'd be sending your credentials unnecessarily to every page, which is a security issue). Read the php [http-auth documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) on this subject for "proper" use of HTTP authentication.

Comment: will the 401 request work with a rest call? What I'm trying to get is the ability to pass username/password in a rest call.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you're not sending the needed parameters properly!
Have you tried `wget http://johnsmith:mypassword@192.168.1.163/my.php`?

Answer (score 0):

For PHP-CGI:

in .htaccess add this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

and at the beginning of your script add this:

```
list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':' , base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));
```

Comment: The author of the question specifically mentioned that his/her "Server API" was set to "Apache 2.0 Handler" and not CGI