# HTTP Authentication With PHP failed to get posted username and password

Tags: php, http, http-headers, http-authentication

Following is my code which I am using to HTTP authenticate. The problem I am facing is I am not able to get the posted values I gave in username and password. Kindly let me know how can I fix this?

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
  if (stripos($actual_link, 'rate') !== false) 
{
$valid_passwords = "abcd";
$valid_users = "loanq";

$user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$pass = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

if ($user != $valid_users || $pass != $valid_passwords)
{
    $validated = false;
}
else
{
    $validated = true;
}

if (!$validated) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Authenticate Yourself"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    die ("Not authorized");
}
}
```

Comment: can we see the html form so we can see how you are forming your post request?

Comment: @Royalty Its HTTP Authentication and you don't put  any form for that. Its auto generated...

Comment: What is it doing, just keeps giving you the login box over and over?

Comment: @developerwjk yes its exactly doing that..

Comment: You should add something like a session variable so that you can stop and inspect the variables after the first failed login instead of generating a new login box.

Comment: Ok, after racking my brain on this and editing the code and thinking I found something, I went back and tried the initial code again, and it actually works.  Its just that I mixed up the username and password because you declare them in reverse order pass/user at the top of the PHP...lol

Comment: @jeroen As per the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053306/http-auth-via-php-php-auth-user-not-set my server is `CGI/FastCGI ` so is there anyway I can use the HTTP authentication without PHP then?

Comment: just wonder, if you debug this - where is your echos? just show us variable values please. and I think first line or almost line must be `if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))` and then you can try to put it into your vars... but anyway echos more often to see where is an error :-)